# how to find config type by API command

Tags: api, hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming, ambari

How to know the configuration type for parameter in ambari cluster by API

examples  of configuration type - core-site, hdfs-site, mapred-queue-acls

lets say I want to find the configuration type for the parameter - "mapreduce.map.memory.mb” , in this case configuration type is mapred-site

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the `org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration` object can access all sorts of hadoop related config. You just have to `conf.get("mapreduce.map.memory.mb")`

Comment: is it possible by API?

Comment: This might be of some help : https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/configuration.md